# Python: How can I use a specific integer from a list?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to programming, and I am having trouble figuring out how to take a specific number from a list like:

```
[12, 3, 4]
```

How could I take the integers and use them, like if I wanted to multiply 12 and 4 or 12 and 3? I am trying to find the first differences of the numbers, so for example 12 - 3 and then 3 - 4.

Note: I am just using those numbers as an example, I need the program to do any integers that the user inputs.
Thanks!

Comment: Not specifically related to your question, but it's probably worth noting that `[12, 3, 4]` is a list of numbers, and `['12', '3', '4']` is a list of strings.

Comment: Sounds like you want list indexing, which lets you get specific items from a list, given its position. Take a look at [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) for more information.

Comment: Oh whoops, I'll change the question.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: How do you decide which ones get multiplied? It doesn't really make much sense what you want. If you want to know how to access an item in a list, then you should ask that question (why you want them is irrelevant)

Comment: Just for the record, if you're wondering why your post is being voted down and want to improve future posts: people expect you to first do a quick search for your problem (ie: Google it) as basic problems are usually often asked and answered. Next, rather than asking for someone to spoon-feed you the answer, it's best to show what code you currently have, what you've tried, and so forth.

Comment: I want it to subtract number by number, like 12 - 3, then 3 - 4, then whatever other numbers could possibly be in the list. It's a parsed list, like I used the .split function in order to seperate the numbers, although it doesnt need to be, I just figured it would be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the integers by calling their position in the list. Here's an example of adding, subtracting, and finding the sum of your list:

```
example = [12, 3, 4]
print(example[0] + example[1]) #15 (12 + 3)
print(example[2] - example[1]) #1 (4 - 3)
print(sum(example)) # 19 (12 + 3 + 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
>>> l = ['12', '3', '4']
>>> def mul(num1, num2):
        if num1 in l and num2 in l:
            return str(int(num1)*int(num2))
        else:
            return 'Number you specified is not present in the list. Please try again'


>>> print(mul(input('Print the num1 : '), input('Print the num2')))
Print the num1 : 1
Print the num2 : 7
Number you specified is not present in the list. Please try again
>>> print(mul(input('Print the num1 : '), input('Print the num2 : ')))
Print the num1 : 3
Print the num2 : 12
36
```